# Do you need to structure an IN for the where clause a certain way?

Tags: apex, trigger

Trying to write a dedupe trigger for the lead. Basically, if the lead is created then it will see if it has an exact match to another lead. If it does then it will update the new lead to show the primary lead as a lookup. My soql seems to not be saving when I am trying to have an in clause twice?

```
trigger FindDupes on Lead (before insert) {
for (Lead myLead : Trigger.new) {
if (myLead.Email != null) {
  List<Lead> dupes = [SELECT Company,Email,Id,Is_Primary__c,Primary_Lead__c,RecordTypeId FROM Lead
                           WHERE Email = :myLead.Email AND Company = :myLead.Company];
  if (dupes.size() > 0) {
    myLead.Primary_Lead__c = dupes[0].Id;
  } else {
    myLead.Primary_Lead__c = null;
    myLead.Is_Primary__c = True;
  }                             
 }
}
}
```

Comment: what error message do you see?

Comment: As an aside, consider using a [Duplicate Rule](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=duplicate_rules_create.htm) instead. It will let you see dupes and/or choose to block them based on your configuration. It also adds a section where you can see duplicate records.

Comment: When I change that I get the following errors.

Unexpected token 'myLead.Company'.
Missing 'IDENTIFIER' at ']'
expecting a colon, found 'myLead.Company'

Comment: We are trying to update to show what the primary record was and not black any of them.

Comment: I just want to add that you should run that query outside of the for loop (imagine a dataload with 200 Leads for example. that would break the SOQL limit). Collect the emails and companies first and use those to query the dupes, and then put them in a map and use that to find the dupes when going through the Leads.

Comment: you have to consider two use cases: intra-batch dups and extra-batch dups

Comment: @JoshuaAnderson You can set Duplicate Rules to "alert" mode, in which case users can still save records, and you'll see the duplicates. Also, the new error you specified does not match your code. You're missing a ":", as the error says. Double-check your work. Also, bulkification of the trigger would be a good idea.

Comment: This is supposed to update the lead record and move it to a duplicate record type. Is this not the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the `&&`. You need to use the word `AND` instead. Similarly, you would use `OR` for an either-or filter.

Comment: sfdcfox, He is using `AND` in SOQL

Comment: @Sarvesh Originally, OP was not, it has been edited.